# How to use SharePoint notification from Event Receiver

Tags: event-receivers

I have an event receiver, which fires when item is being deleted ( ItemDeleting event ). I have some logic that checks whether item can be deleted or not, and if it can't, I need to show notification message - reason why item can't be deleted.

Now I would like to use SharePoint notifications, to have notification appear on the upper right corner, under the ribbons panel.

Any ideas how can I do that ? Or is it even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can get the call of the Javascript from the EventReceiver to the browser is through the [SPEventPropertiesBase.RedirectUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventpropertiesbase.redirecturl), but unfortunately you can't just specify `javascript:...` so you may have to:

- Add something to your master page looking for a query parameter and showing the notification if that query parameter is present
- In the EventReceiver set RedirectUrl to the original Url + the special query parameter

You should check it this code works as you want in all scenarios like when the users open an item in a dialog box (view/edit) and clicks delete, ...

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach. Requires few more cases to track ( as you mentioned, if user opens up dialog and deletes item from there ), but seems the only way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you might like to have a look at the below links, which should solve your purpose!

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-creating-alerts-in-sharepoint-2010/

http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/articles/pages/notificationsnstatus.aspx

Comment: Thanks for links, I don't think alerts would work for me, what I intended to use is notifications, and second link you've provided is all about it, thou I'm looking for a way to use it from Event Receiver.